# does postgres select nextval causing some performance issues?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using doctrine ORM which inserting each record as a separate query in one transaction for example like this:

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO table (id, label, position) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO table (id, label, position,) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO table (id, label, position) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
COMMIT
```

but depends on a doctrine query log before that it's also doing

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq')
SELECT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq')
SELECT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq')
```

to be able to generate next id, but it's done not in the single transaction.

So I'm trying to understand is it in the same request to database, or it making separate requests for each `invtal`, and can it cause some performance issues in case of like a thousands inserts?? Thanks!

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table (
    id integer NOT NULL ,
    table character varying(255),
    position character varying(255)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE public.table_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

generated by DoctrineORM, and also actuall migration generated by DoctrineORM to create table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE TABLE table (id INT NOT NULL, label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Here is the result of `psql` `\d table`:

```
                         Table "public.table"
    Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id           | integer                |           | not null | 
 label        | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 position     | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Why not let the database assign the value? That's how IDs are typically assigned

Comment: well, I do not know... from code/application perspective my ids are autoincrement fields, I do not know why postgres making sequences for that, I thought that's a way how postgres doing it?  or maybe that's how doctrine ORM managing it?

Comment: can it be done without sequences??? When ORM generates migrations for each table it also add `CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1` for each table

Comment: To your question add the schema for one of the tables by  using `psql` and then `\d <table_name>`

Comment: That is not what I asked for. Follow the instructions from my previous comment.

Comment: Also add the the ORM table definition to your question.

Comment: what do you mean by "add the schema for one of the tables"?? schema and table are different things, one schema, can contain multiple tables, sorry but 'm not following

Comment: Schema means two things: 1) A `schema` namespace that you refer to. 2) The definition of an object in a database e.g. table definition.  You yourself referred to the `CREATE TABLE ` definition that way in your question.  In any case open `psql` and do `\d <table_name>` and add the result to your question. Please do not post the ORM queries any more, I am interested in what is actually in the database.

Comment: Alright so the ORM, per usual, picked the worse strategy. Add to your question the table definition as described in the model. I'm guessing `id` has `@GeneratedValue` per here [Identifiers](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys). Read that section for your options. I'm thinking `IDENTITY` is what you want. Test on a new test_table to see if it does add a `SERIAL` or `IDENTITY` column either of which would have a `DEFAULT` of a sequence.

Comment: so if I'll pick up `IDENTITY` as a strategy, PostgreSQL'll use the `SERIAL` type, but is it really needed? I did not tell you I do not want to use `SEQUENCES`, my question was does `SEQUENCES` adds some overhead? Does `SERIAL` better than `SEQUENCES`?? From what I read so far it looks like in terms of performance they are the same, but  `SEQUENCES` are more flexible. If it's fine to use `SEQUENCES` I do not want to change it. But I come from MySQL and it's weird to see 6 queries instead of 3 when I want to insert 3 rows

Comment: To answer your original question about performance I would take a look at [Sequence functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). They are the sequences are optimized for performance in sequence fetching. There could be some performance hit with very large batches, though that would need to be verified. The biggest issue with the current ORM procedure is that is decouples the sequence from the table, so any other client would not 'know' about the relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236611/discussion-between-bogdan-dubyk-and-adrian-klaver).

Comment: okay, please create an answer and I'll accept it, and we can continue in chat. Thank you very much, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq')` queries are occurring because the ORM has created a decoupled `sequence` for the table. In that the `sequence` is created but is not 'attached' to the `table.id` column via either a `SERIAL` type or `IDENTITY` column. This means the ORM has to make separate queries to fetch the next sequence value in order to supply a value to the `id` column.